# Using the exchange lemma for proofs

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I recently learned about the exchange lemma (which is an extremely difficult concept to understand, in my opinion), and I'm trying to do a couple of proofs:

Proof 1: Suppose $V$ is a n-dimensional vector space over $F$ and $S \subset V$ is a finite subset.
Use the Exchange Lemma to prove that if $|S| < n$, then $S$ is not a spanning set.

Proof 2: Suppose $V$ is a n-dimensional vector space over $F$ and $S \subset V$ is a finite subset. Use
the Exchange Lemma to prove that if $|S| > n$, then $S$ is linearly dependent.

My attempts:

Proof 1: Suppose $V$ has a basis $G = \{v_1, ... , v_n\}$ and S contains vectors $u_1, ... , u_m$ s.t. $m < n$. It follows that since $|S|$ = $m < n$,

$$|S| < dim(V)$$

Hence, $S$ is not a spanning set.

Proof 2: Again, suppose $V$ has a basis $G = \{v_1, ... , v_n\}$ and S contains vectors $u_1, ... , u_m$. This time, however, $n < m$. By linear independence of bases:

$$a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n = 0 \implies a_1 = ... = a_n = 0$$

Since $|S| = m > n$,

$$b_1u_1 + ... + b_mu_m = 0 \implies b_1u_1 + ... + b_nu_n + ... + b_mu_m = 0$$

$\implies$ $u_i$ for $i = n+1 ... m$ are redundant.

Thus, $S$ is linearly dependent.

I'm pretty sure these proofs are way off and don't even use the exchange lemma (can't figure out how to utilize the lemma) but any assistance or corrections are much appreciated.

Comment: You should state exactly what you mean by the "exchange lemma". I don't think this is universal terminology.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. The Steinitz exchange lemma that the replacement theorem follows from?